# Calling a method using @Async vs Calling the method in a new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

Which one should I choose? I can either annotate the java function with `@Async` or else I can call the function in a `new Thread`, e.g. Java 8 like this

```
new Thread(() -> {
            myfunction("Test");
        }).start();
```

Is there a difference between these 2 ways ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use Thread directly use a ExecutorService: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: +1 to @keuleJ 's comment. If you use `@Async` in Spring, then the async op will be executed on a thread pool, i.e. executor service. The standard Spring's executor will be used unless you define your own executor.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html:

> By default, Spring will be searching for an associated thread pool
>   definition: either a unique TaskExecutor bean in the context, or an
>   Executor bean named “taskExecutor” otherwise. If neither of the two is
>   resolvable, a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor will be used to process async
>   method invocations.

### Similarity:

both your example and `@Async` are similar in the fact that they can be executed in a separated thread

### Difference:

the difference is that annotating a method of a bean with @Async will make it execute in a **separate** thread which is given from a **thread pool** and not directly in a thread as in your case.